# "~ with I'm in ~" : How should I interpret this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> During that time, I got way more nervous with I'm in physical contact with him.

What's the thing possibly omitted between ***with*** and ***I'm in***? Or if that's grammatical and being seen natural to natives, what am I missing?

Comment: The sentence is ungrammatical as written. What's the context? Where have you taken it from?

Comment: @Gustavson Thanks. It's satisfying enough just to know it's ungrammatical. The sentence is from some third-rate novel which was double translated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sentence is ungrammatical and, at the point of the grammar error, incomprehensible. Absent any context, I would guess *with* was an error for *when*, or *I'm* was an error for *being*.

I'm not aware of any English dialect in which that would be considered an acceptable sentence.

Comment: Thanks. It's satisfying enough just to know it's ungrammatical. The sentence is from some third-rate novel which was double translated.

Comment: Another possibility is that "with" should be replaced by "with when".

Comment: @Jasper: That would at least make meaning clear, though I find it unappealingly redundant. I'm sure it's a perfectly natural way to say it for some folks, though.